# How to use mount() system call in Solaris 11 to mount zfs? What arguments and mount options to be provided?

Tags: c, solaris

I want to use mount() to mount zfs in Solaris 11. I am not sure which basic options and arguments to be provided. I have already gone through the Solaris 11 Administrative guide as follows.

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23823_01/html/817-5093/fscreate-6.html#gkcot

I have seen that the mount() has different signature in Solaris as below.

mount (device_id, mount_point, flags, file_system_type, fs_arguments, sizeof_fs_arguments, fs_options, sizeof_fs_options);

Can I get any help on this?

P.S. - I had already tried with the device available in my system by using fstyp on /dev/rdsk/dev_name in first argument in mount(). I was getting ENOENT as error.

Comment: Here's how ZFS does it:  http://src.illumos.org/source/xref/illumos-gate/usr/src/lib/libzfs/common/libzfs_mount.c#375

Comment: There is an argument zfs_handle_t. How to get that? How can we create for  us?